# How to use Keras LSTM with word embeddings to predict word id's

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I have problems understanding how to get the correct output when using word embeddings in Keras. My settings are as follows:

- My input are batches of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length)`. Each row
  in a batch represents one sentence, the word are represented by word id's. The
  sentences are padded with zeros such that all are of the same length.
  For example a `(3,6)` input batch might look like: `np.array([[135600],[174580],[138272]])`
- My targets are given by the input batch shifted one step to the right.
  So for each input word I want to predict the next word: `np.array([[356000],[745800],[382720]])`
- I feed such an input batch into the Keras embedding layer. My embedding
  size is 100, so the output will be a 3D tensor of shape `(batch_size,
  sequence_length, embedding_size)`. So in the little example its `(3,6,100)`
- This 3D batch is fed into an LSTM layer
- The output of the LSTM layer is fed into a Dense layer with
  `(sequence_length)` output neurons having a softmax activation
  function. So the shape of the output will be like the shape of the input namely `(batch_size, sequence_length)`
- As a loss I am using the categorical crossentropy between the input and target batch

My question:

The output batch will contain probabilities because of the
softmax activation function. But what I want is the network to predict
integers such that the output fits the target batch of integers.
How can I "decode" the output such that I know which word the network is predicting? Or do I have to construct the network differently?

**Edit 1:**

I have changed the output and target batches from 2D arrays to 3D tensors. So instead of using a target batch of size `(batch_size, sequence_length)` with integer id's I am now using a one-hot encoded 3D target tensor `(batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)`. To get the same format as an output of the network, I have changed the network to output sequences (by setting `return_sequences=True` in the LSTM layer). Further, the number of output neurons was changed to `vocab_size` such that the output layer now produces a batch of size `(batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)`.
With this 3D encoding I can get the predicted word id using `tf.argmax(outputs, 2)`. This approach seems to work for the moment but I would still be interested whether it's possible to keep the 2D targets/outputs

Answer (score 1):

One, solution, perhaps not the best, is to output one-hot vectors the size of of your dictionary (including dummy words).

Your last layer must output `(sequence_length, dictionary_size+1)`.

Your dense layer will already output the `sequence_length` if you don't add any `Flatten()` or `Reshape()` before it, so it should be a `Dense(dictionary_size+1)`

You can use the functions `keras.utils.to_categorical()` to transform an integer in a one-hot vector and `keras.backend.argmax()` to transform a one=hot vector into an integer.

Unfortunately, this is sort of unpacking your embedding. It would be nice if it were possible to have a reverse embedding or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I have already done something similar (see edited question). I was hoping that there would be a way to use 2D targets and outputs